# Localized DateTime Control for an SWT application

Tags: java, datetime, localization, widget, eclipse-rcp

I'm using Eclipse RCP and I'm looking for a DateTime Control which can be localized. Before I write my own I wish to know whethere there are some ready-to-use alternatives.

Although a Calendar object can be localized according to this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=248075) this is not true for the DateTime Control.

Do you have any ideas?
Any SWT or JFace (?) Control will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the [nebula CDateTime Widget](http://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php) you can enter a localized date-pattern, for details see http://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php?page=patterns